# Help with test classes for VisualforcePage Redirect controller

Tags: visualforce, class, pagereference, redirect, test-setup

I'm very new with apex, and having a lot of trouble getting code coverage for my tests.

Here's my Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Task" >
<apex:enhancedlist type="Activity" height="800" rowsPerPage="50" listId="00B17000000UpeY"/>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class TasksController {
    public PageReference redirect() {
        return new PageReference('007?fcf=00B1a000000N1wh&rolodexIndex=-1&page=1');
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
private class Test_TasksTab {

    static testMethod void myTest() {

        PageReference pageRef = Page.Tasks_Tab;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        TasksController controller = new TasksController()
    }
}
```

I know this must be incredibly simple. The test passes but I'm still getting 0% code coverage. Help?

Comment: Your VisualForce Page does not use the controller you defined and it is, in fact, an extension in this context if you were to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community!  After you instantiate the controller (which you've already done), you need to call the redirect() method explicitly and then assert that
It returned the PageReference you expected.